# How I create this PHP array correctly?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am having a PHP array like below:

```
$categories = array(
    array('id' => 1,  'parent' => 0, 'name' => 'Category A'),
    array('id' => 2,  'parent' => 0, 'name' => 'Category B'),
    array('id' => 3,  'parent' => 0, 'name' => 'Category C'),
    array('id' => 4,  'parent' => 0, 'name' => 'Category D'),
    array('id' => 5,  'parent' => 0, 'name' => 'Category E'),
    array('id' => 6,  'parent' => 2, 'name' => 'Subcategory F'),
    array('id' => 7,  'parent' => 2, 'name' => 'Subcategory G'),
    array('id' => 8,  'parent' => 3, 'name' => 'Subcategory H'),
    array('id' => 9,  'parent' => 4, 'name' => 'Subcategory I'),
    array('id' => 10, 'parent' => 9, 'name' => 'Subcategory J'),
);
```

When looping above array, I want to create another array inside foreach.
That array should be something like this:

```
$cats[$parent][$id] = $name;
```

This is how I tried it.

```
  foreach ($categories as $key => $value) {        
    // echo '<pre>', print_r($value). '</pre>';
    // echo $value['id'];
    $cats[$value['parent']][$value['id']] = $value['name'];   
  }
```

But its not working for me. Not work mean, its create wrong array.

Can anybody help me out. Thank you.

Comment: you want to seperate array of names?

Comment: @HikmatSijapati, What you mean "seperate array of names"?

Answer (score 0):

Like this.Make array of categories.

```
<?php

$categories = array(
    array('id' => 1,  'parent' => 0, 'name' => 'Category A'),
    array('id' => 2,  'parent' => 0, 'name' => 'Category B'),
    array('id' => 3,  'parent' => 0, 'name' => 'Category C'),
    array('id' => 4,  'parent' => 0, 'name' => 'Category D'),
    array('id' => 5,  'parent' => 0, 'name' => 'Category E'),
    array('id' => 6,  'parent' => 2, 'name' => 'Subcategory F'),
    array('id' => 7,  'parent' => 2, 'name' => 'Subcategory G'),
    array('id' => 8,  'parent' => 3, 'name' => 'Subcategory H'),
    array('id' => 9,  'parent' => 4, 'name' => 'Subcategory I'),
    array('id' => 10, 'parent' => 9, 'name' => 'Subcategory J'),
);

 foreach ($categories as $key => $value) {        

    $cats[$value['parent']][$value['id']][]= $value['name'];   
  }

  print_r($cats);
```

Comment: Actually I want to create separate  array like this `$cats[$parent][$id] = $name; `

Answer (score 0):

You want like this

```
<?php
$categories = array(
array('id' => 1,  'parent' => 0, 'name' => 'Category A'),
array('id' => 2,  'parent' => 0, 'name' => 'Category B'),
array('id' => 3,  'parent' => 0, 'name' => 'Category C'),
array('id' => 4,  'parent' => 0, 'name' => 'Category D'),
array('id' => 5,  'parent' => 0, 'name' => 'Category E'),
array('id' => 6,  'parent' => 2, 'name' => 'Subcategory F'),
array('id' => 7,  'parent' => 2, 'name' => 'Subcategory G'),
array('id' => 8,  'parent' => 3, 'name' => 'Subcategory H'),
array('id' => 9,  'parent' => 4, 'name' => 'Subcategory I'),
array('id' => 10, 'parent' => 9, 'name' => 'Subcategory J'),
);
$newarray = array();
foreach($categories as $array)
{
  $newarray[$array['parent']][$array['id']] = $array['name'];
}
print_r($newarray);
```

Comment: yea please we can